# S-Docs for Salesforce - Inserting Hyperlinks

Tags: lightning, managed-package, pdf, s-docs

I’m using the free version of S-Docs for PDF generation on Opportunities. Although the [help documentation](https://www.sdocs.com/knowledge-base/sdocs/creating-templates/overview-the-s-docs-template-editor/#8) mentions being able to insert hyperlinks in the template editor, I do not see this button as an option.
Is it possible to add hyperlinks to the template? Can users add hyperlinks when they edit the SDoc after it’s generated in the Opportunity?

For reference, this photo is from SDocs help and shows the insert hyperlink option:

[image]

This is an example of the inset actions currently available within the org:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

S-Docs Support answered an email posing this question.

[image: S-Docs Support Email Answer]

> Salesforce quietly removed this option from the editor in a recent
> update. Please simply add an anchor tag () in the source to achieve
> the same result. We are releasing a new Template Editor in the first
> half of next year that uses a higher quality base editor and this
> functionality will be restored along with countless other
> improvements.

I have tested and can confirm the following:

- From the S-Docs Template editor, you can access the source code and add in  tags to display/create the necessary links upon S-Docs creation. It should be noted, users can not edit this from the UI if you're allowing User edits once the doc is created.

  - Ex: `<a href="url">link text</a>`
- Users can copy-paste a pre-formatted link into a specific created S-Doc if they want something different than what the template populates, assuming Users are given the ability to Edit created S-Docs.

Although the work-around is not the most convenient, I'm happy to see S-Docs Support will be updating the editor in the first half of 2024.  For now, the workaround is sufficient and users/orgs can still achieve using hyperlinks within PDF-generated S-Docs.